# toggle switch custom doesn't work in datatable using laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, toggleswitch

I added a toggle switch custom to my datatable , using the following code :

```
          function getdata(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        return datatables()->of(Casting::latest()->get())
            ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                $button = '<table><tr><td>';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Modifier</button>';
                $button .= '</td><td>';
                 $button .= ' <div class="custom-control custom-switch">';
                $button .= ' <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="switch1" name="example"';
                
                if ($data->status == 1) {

                    $button .= "checked";
                }

                $button .= '><label class="custom-control-label" for="switch1">Toggle me</label>
    </div>';
                $button .= '</td></tr></table>';
                return $button;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
    }
    return view('Casting.castingss');
}
```

But I get a checkbox instead of a toggle switch custom.

[image]

**EDIT**

Now I get That :

[image]

But I can switch just the first row thr other rows stay fixed

Comment: which js are you using for switch custom .also show if it has jquery for toggle

Comment: @JohnLobo , I'm using that https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_custom_switch&stacked=h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi u should define the div before the switch button like this

the css will be :

```
  <style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


</style>
```

and the code will be :

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

for exemple if u delete all the css i put in here and add let only the first

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

u will get only checkbox the u can edit it as u like with css :D i hope i helped u Good luck

Comment: thank you for your help, it works for me but I didn't get the CSS that I wanted, but it works, Now I can switch all the rows of Datatable